Sending a list of objects through Pun RPC in Unity optimization
I've got a dictionary which holds GameTiles with the key set to a vector2int for grid position. I need to send a bunch of these GameTiles through PunRPC. Is this the best way to do it or would there be a better way. I created these two tools to help me.
public static string Tiles2String(List<GameTile> _tileList)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (GameTile i in _tileList)
    {
        result += ":" + i.gridLocation.ToString();
    }
    return result.Substring(1);
}

public static List<GameTile> String2Tiles(string _tileString)
{
    string[] stringArray = _tileString.Split(':');
    List<GameTile> result = new List<GameTile>();
    foreach (string str in stringArray) 
    {
        string vector = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
        string[] vector2split = vector.Split(",");
        int x = int.Parse(vector2split[0]);
        int y = int.Parse(vector2split[1]);
        GameTile tile = BattleManager.Instance.gameTiles[new Vector2Int(x,y)];
        result.Add(tile);
    }
    return result;
}


A simple way to optimize this would be to send the numbers as actual numbers (as bytes), rather than as a string.
You can send an object[] through a PunRPC, as long as the elements are serializable by Photon. Vector2Int isn't serializable, but it's easy to add as a custom serializable class:
// Run this in a Start method or something
// "123" is a unique byte identifier for this class
PhotonPeer.RegisterType(typeof(Vector2Int), 123, SerializeVector2Int, DeserializeVector2Int)

public static object DeserializeVector2Int(StreamBuffer inStream, short length)
{
    Vector2Int newVector = new Vector2Int();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    inStream.Read(bytes, 0, 8);
    int index = 0;
    Protocol.Deserialize(out newVector.x, memVector2, ref index);
    Protocol.Deserialize(out newVector.y, memVector2, ref index);

    return newVector;
}

public static short SerializeVector2Int(StreamBuffer outStream, object obj)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8]; // Two ints take 8 bytes
    int index = 0;
    Protocol.Serialize(vo.x, bytes, ref index);
    Protocol.Serialize(vo.y, bytes, ref index);
    outStream.Write(bytes, 0, 8);

    return 8;  // Two ints take 8 bytes
}

Then, you can just pass in the gridLocations as an array to the RPC:
Vector2Int[] locations = _tileList.Select(tile => tile.gridLocation).ToArray();
RPC_DoSomething(locations);


[PunRPC]
public void RPC_DoSomething(object[] tiles) {
   ...
}

